# A flag to inform moderators of questions answered, but not accepted for a long time

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flagging

For example

[Why doesn't the Windows command prompt window maximize to the full screen size?](https://superuser.com/questions/80094/why-doesnt-the-windows-command-prompt-window-maximize-to-the-full-screen-size)

Its more than 2 years old

It has been answered as well

Perhaps there should be a flag to inform moderators of such cases to avoid these questions from being bumped to the top even though they are answered?

Comment: In addition to what's mentioned in the two answers, there is already a part of the 10k moderation tool that lists *late answers* (recent answers to old topics) to allow better community review ("*These are late answers to old questions provided by users with less than 10 reputation.*").

Comment: Isn't reviewing possible with less rep now? @dan

Comment: @slhck I thought I'd fixed my comment, it's part of review, not the tools. Should be around 2-5k rep.

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2879/is-it-wrong-to-ask-people-to-accept-an-answer-to-their-question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First the question was bumped because someone added an answer. This is, and always will be, intended behavior (non-bumping "minor" edits have been refused multiple times, and with good reason). Of course, this is the same for questions with an accepted answer as well - they will be bumped if new answers are added (again, intentional behavior).

We could protect (stop low-rep users answering) or lock (stop anyone doing anything) the question to prevent a few these, but why? If it's a valid new answer then there's no harm it being added (if it's not we need the question bumping so we can see and remove it).

---

#### As for the acceptance of an answer:

Currently no one except the original asker can accept an answer.
Even in the case of the original asker being NA, as in this example.

Providing a moderator or community way to override this has been discussed many times (see links at end) and it is very unlikely anything of this nature will ever be implemented.

As such I'm afraid that flagging them for us (or anyone else) is pointless.

---

[Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period)

[Allow users to mark "accepted" answer on someone else's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/allow-users-to-mark-accepted-answer-on-someone-elses-question)

Plus loads of inbound duplicate links (check the "linked" on the right of these two).

Answer (score 8):

Moderators don't have such super powers, we can't accept questions for other users nor can we alter the sorting order on the question pages.

Besides, its not always a bad thing to have old questions float to the frontpage, perhaps they're outdated or a good answer teaches you something you didn't know.

If you don't want to see such questions, simply use one of the different filters that don't show these questions (like Newest)